# Highcharts graph default series fillColor overrides the state fillColors (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to be able to set the fill color of a boxplot series, then override that color on certain states (hover and select).

The issue is, any time I set the default fillColor, the hover and select states no longer work, and only the default fillColor is used.

If no default fillcolor is set, then the state fillColors also don't work (I guess because they rely on the fillColor property already being set to work).

However, if I set the default fillColor to an invalid setting like '#fsdfrw4jh432', then it "sorta" works. That is, the states now work.

See this jsfiddle to see what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/wiseguy205/b3CuF/1/

As you can see from that jsfiddle, the hover and select states work, though the fill color starts out black because it's an invalid color code. If you change the color code to a correct color, then the states no longer work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the jsfiddle code btw:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'boxplot'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Box Plot Example'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            states:{
                hover: {
                    enabled: true,
                    lineWidth: 5,
                     fillColor: '#0F0'
                },
                select: {
                     fillColor: '#F00',
                    enabled: 'true'
                }
            },
            fillColor:  '#00dddddF',
        }
    },


    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        title: {
            text: 'Experiment No.'
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Observations'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 932,
            color: 'red',
            width: 1,
            label: {
                text: 'Theoretical mean: 932',
                align: 'center',
                style: {
                    color: 'gray'
                }
            }
        }]  
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Observations',
        data: [
            [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
            [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
            [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
            [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
            [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
        ],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Outlier',
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
            [0, 644],
            [4, 718],
            [4, 951],
            [4, 969]
        ],
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'white',
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
    }]

});
    // the button action
$('#button').click(function() {
    var selectedPoints = $('#container').highcharts().getSelectedPoints();
    alert ('You selected '+ selectedPoints.length +' points');
});
```

});

Comment: Reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2340).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I developed a workaround for this bug that people can use until the highcharts team actually patches it.

Here is the jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/b3CuF/16/

Here is the actual code for posterity:

```
$(function () {
var savedFill ='#2c8';
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'boxplot',
        events: {
            load: function(event) {

                var todayT = $('#container').highcharts();
                //console.log(this);
                //console.log(this.series[0].data);
                //this.series.data[0].pointAttr[''].fill = savedFill;
                //this.series.data[0].select();                    
                for (var i=0;i<this.series[0].data.length;i++){
                    //this.series.data[i].select();
                    console.log(this.series[0].data[i]);
                    this.series[0].data[i].select();
                    console.log(i);
                    if (i == this.series[0].data.length-1){

                        this.series[0].data[0].select(false);

                    }



                }

                //this.series[0].data[0].unselect();
                //this.series[0].data[4].select(false);

            }
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Box Plot Example'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            states:{
                hover: {
                    enabled: true,
                    lineWidth: 5,
                     fillColor: '#0F0'
                },
                select: {
                     fillColor: savedFill,
                    enabled: 'true'
                }
            },
            fillColor:  'notNull',
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function(e) {                        
                        //console.log($('#container').highcharts());
                        var hChartObj = $('#container').highcharts();

                        //hChartObj.series[0].update({
                        //    color: '#FF0000'
                        //});
                        //this.update({
                        //    color: '#FF0000'
                        //});
                        //console.log(this.series.data[0]);
                        console.log(Object.keys(this.series.data[0].pointAttr));
                        //console.log(this);
                        this.series.data[0].pointAttr.hover.fill = '#60d0ff';
                        this.series.data[0].pointAttr.select.fill = '#ff6081';
                        this.series.data[0].pointAttr[''].fill = savedFill;
                        //this.series.data[0].pointAttr.%20.fill = '#ff6081';
                        //this.series.data[0].pointAttr.fill = {fill:'#60d0ff',stroke:'#2f7ed8',stroke-width:1};
                        //this.series.data[0].graphic.fill = '#000000';
                        //this.series.data[0].series.color = '#000000';
                        //this.series.data[0].box.fill = '#60d0ff';
                        //console.log('updated');
                        //console.log(this.series.data[0].pointAttr);
                        //this.update({
                        //    name: 'yup'
                        //});
                        //this.series.data[0].graphic.fill('destroy');
                        //this.series.data[0].graphic.fill = '#000000';
                        //hChartObj.series[0].remove(true);

                    },
                    mouseOut: function() {                        
                        console.log('out');
                        //this.series.data[0].pointAttr.hover.fill = savedFill;
                        //console.log(this.series.data[0].pointAttr);
                    },
                    select: function() {
                        this.series.data[0].pointAttr[''].fill = savedFill;
                    },
                    unselect: function() {
                        this.series.data[0].pointAttr[''].fill = savedFill;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },


    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        title: {
            text: 'Experiment No.'
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Observations'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 932,
            color: 'red',
            width: 1,
            label: {
                text: 'Theoretical mean: 932',
                align: 'center',
                style: {
                    color: 'gray'
                }
            }
        }]  
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Observations',
        data: [
            [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
            [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
            [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
            [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
            [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
        ],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Outlier',
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
            [0, 644],
            [4, 718],
            [4, 951],
            [4, 969]
        ],
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'white',
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
    }]

});
    // the button action
$('#button').click(function() {
    var selectedPoints = $('#container').highcharts().getSelectedPoints();
    alert ('You selected '+ selectedPoints.length +' points');
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement to change the outline of the boxes.  Not quite the same, but since I couldn't find anything out there for it, I'll post an [example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronogan/o0hn519w/).

The main point being:

```
var colorBox = function(point, selected) {
    var series = point.series,
        seriesOptions = series.options,
        seriesStates = seriesOptions.states,
        stem = point.stem,
        box = point.box,
        whiskers = point.whiskers,
        medianShape = point.medianShape;

    var selectedStroke = seriesStates.select
        ? seriesStates.select.color
        : null;
    var stroke = selected
        ? selectedStroke
        : point.color || series.color;

    stem.attr({ 'stroke': stroke });
    box.attr({ 'stroke': stroke });
    whiskers.attr({ 'stroke': stroke });
    medianShape.attr({ 'stroke': stroke });
};
```